# CreateFile() method returns ERROR_NOACCESS error

Tags: c++, windows, certificate, x509certificate

I was trying to create a certificate file via `CreateFile()` method but the `HANDLE` for CreateFile is not able to create.

```
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;     
sa.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
sa.bInheritHandle = FALSE;


HANDLE hStoreFileHandle = CreateFile(
        "D:\\temp.cer",
        GENERIC_WRITE,      // Access mode
        0,                  // Share mode
        &sa,                // Security 
        CREATE_ALWAYS,      // How to create the file
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        // File attributes
        NULL);
```

But, hStoreFileHandle (`HANDLE`) was not able to create. `GetLastError()` returns code 998 [check here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/system-error-codes--500-999-) which means `ERROR_NOACCESS` (Invalid access to memory location)

I didn't get what's wrong in my code here.

Comment: Try `SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa = {};` for your first line.

Comment: You have left most of the `sa` structure uninitialised.

Comment: @MikeVine,user:3370124  it's working now